# Run Data Driven Subscription (SSRS Report) for every one hour programmatically

Tags: reporting-services, cmd, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, data-driven

Before i was trying to deploy the SSRS reports in Report Server.Now it was successfully deploy and got knowledge from this [link](http://sqlrows.blogspot.in/2012/03/dynamic-deploy-of-ssrs-reports-using-vb.html).

Now Again I need to send the report to my client every 1 hour.

I m using Express Edition of SQL Server.so i can't do Data Driven Subscription using my version.

Can i do this Dynamic scheduling of data driven programmatically?

Is there any sample example seen? Please shed some light to my search. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is basically a different question from the one you originally asked. If you need to ask a new question, please create one instead of editing and overwriting your original question, as the answers will no longer make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean you are using some kind of external scheduler and you want to be able to generate Reporting Services reports programmatically using the web service.

You can do this using the [rs Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx), which enables you to execute a Vb.Net script against the web service.

There is an example of using this approach to render a report [here](http://skamie.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/using-rs-exe-to-render-ssrs-reports/).

Comment: RS scripting has trade-offs in terms of development. It's only 10% harder to write your own program that uses the web service. But, doing so allows you to use a Visual Studio project, where it'll be 75% easier to code. One benefit of scripting is that it's source-only; so, you don't have to manage both source and a binary. A compromise is a VB.NET project that uses conditional compliation statements so the code is valid both for developing in Visual Studio and for running with the RS utility. (Note: the docs say an RS script should have a particular extension but .vb works just fine.)

Comment: You're right in principle, the rs utility is really only intended for performing administration tasks, however the question did originally ask for a solution to render reports using the command line.